# CruiseControl with Maven2

Tags: svn, maven-2, cruisecontrol

I'am trying to configure CruiseControl. I need to integrate CruiseControl with SVN and Maven2. I have 4 maven-projects in java that haves one main pom.xml file and each project has is own pom.xml. I already tried lots of configurations but nothing... We are using jenkins in the moment but for my cloeg work i have to test CruiseControl.
Can anyone give me some tips?

This is my config.xml:

```
<bootstrappers>
    <currentbuildstatusbootstrapper file="C:\dev\maven\work\cruisecontrol\logs\Reports\status.txt" />
</bootstrappers>

<modificationset>
    <svn localWorkingCopy="C:\dev\maven\work\cruisecontrol\checkout\Reports" repositoryLocation="..." />
    <maven2snapshotdependency pomfile= "C:\Program Files (x86)\cruisecontrol-2.8.4\main\target\test-classes\net\sourceforge\cruisecontrol\sourcecontrols\maven2-pom.xml" user="fabio.martins" />
</modificationset>

<schedule interval="300">
    <maven2 goal ="clean compile" projectfile="C:\dev\maven\work\cruisecontrol\checkout\Reports\pom.xml" mvnhome="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\maven-2.2.1" mvnscript="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\maven-2.2.1\bin\mvn.bat" />
</schedule>

<log dir= "C:\dev\maven\work\cruisecontrol\logs\Reports" encoding="ISO-8859-1">
    <merge dir= "C:\dev\maven\work\cruisecontrol\checkout\Reports" pattern = "TEST-*.xml"/>
</log>

<publishers>
    <currentbuildstatuspublisher file="C:\dev\maven\work\cruisecontrol\logs\Reports\status.txt"/>
</publishers>
```